# Why do my network response times not add up to the total reported by Chrome dev tools? Node on WSL2

Tags: node.js, networking, google-chrome-devtools, response, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've recently been using WSL2 for development of of a node.js / express back-end service for a web application. I have noticed that some requests take significantly longer than they were doing so before when launched with Docker on MacOS - up to 300-400ms total.

Some of this is explained by time spent "Stalled" as reported by the chrome developer tools' Network tab. But some requests take a long time - which is not explained by anything reported by network inspector. Here's an example showing a request with 350ms total response time - but only 43ms TTFB and effectively no reported time spent queueing or being stalled.

Screenshot of Chrome Dev Tools network request analysis

[image]

Has anyone else seen this before or have any ideas where the extra time is coming from? The numbers provided add up to circa 50ms yet it is reporting total response time at 350ms. Running node inside / outside of a docker container make no difference to this phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this issue - this occurred while sending requests to `localhost` but using `127.0.0.1` to reach it instead made the issue go away. Response times reported by chrome dev tools now correspond to the sum of their parts using `127.0.0.1`.

No idea why. Any comments would be appreciated if there's a reason why localhost lookup in WSL2 causes this mysterious extra latency.